# Регулярные выражения. Добавить слеш в конец строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть ссылка `comp/add` нужно с помощью preg_match добавить слеш в конец выражения, чтобы получилось `comp/add/`.

Пробовал такой вариант:

```
if (preg_match('/^(.+)[^\/]$/ui', 'comp/add', $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Но съедает один символ с конца строки. Поправьте пожалуйста, кто знает.

Comment: `$str = 'ываываыв sfsdf comp/add ыва цк';

$newstr = str_replace('comp/add', 'comp/add/', $str);

echo $newstr;`

Comment: `preg_replace('/([^\/])$/', '$1/', 'comp/add')`, @АлексейШиманский, а если на конце уже будет слэш? Тогда не надо добавлять же )

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нужно поправить регулярное выражение `/^(.+)[^\/]$/ui`

Comment: @Pavel, а что вы ожидаете от своего выражения? `preg_match` не заменяет, а просто показывает что совпало. Если вам надо, чтобы совпало без слеша, то так и пишите: `'/^(.+[^\/])\/+$/ui'`

Comment: @ВОРОН  нужно, чтобы выражение со слэшем не совпадало с регулярным выражением. А выражения без слэша на конце попадали в $matches.
`/^(.+)[^\/]$/ui` -  работает, но съедает одну букву на конце - получается ссылка `comp/ad`   вместо `comp/add`

Comment: просто возьмите последний символ в те же скобки `^(.+[^\/])$`

Comment: @splash58 СПАСИБО! Работает!)

Answer (score 3):

```
$path = rtrim($path, "/") . "/";
```

Comment: это слишком легко, так и квадратные уравнения через дискриминант решать начнем

Answer (score -1):

Нужно все заключить в скобки - в 1 группу:

```
^(.+[^\/])$
```